# Identity Server4 invalid authorization_code

Tags: .net-6, identityserver4

Я успешно получил мой код авторизации через ендпоинт connect/authorize. Теперь когда я пробую обменять мой код авторизации на токен доступа, то получаю ошибку в журнале "invalid authorization_code".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Перепробовал многие подсказки и решения в гугле, но в моей ситуации ничто из этого не решило мою проблему, ошибка так и осталась.
Вот модель запроса:

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Метод создает модель запроса к Identity Server для получения токена доступа по коду авторизации.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tokenEndpoint">Ендпоинт Identity Server.</param>
        /// <param name="code">Код авторизации.</param>
        /// <returns>Модель запроса.</returns>
        public static AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest CreateAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(string? tokenEndpoint,
            string code)
        {
            var tokenRequest = new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
            {
                Address = tokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = "identity_client",
                ClientSecret = "identity_secret",
                Code = code,
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:7176",
                GrantType = GrantType.AuthorizationCode,
                CodeVerifier = CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(),
            };

            return tokenRequest;
        }
```

Вот как дергаю ендпоинт token/connect:

```
   var authorizationCodeTokenRequest = CreateIdentityRequestFactory.CreateAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                    disco.TokenEndpoint, authorizationCode);
                var tokenResponse = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(authorizationCodeTokenRequest);
```

Но в результате получаю ошибку, что код авторизации невалидный. Что я упускаю?
Мой код авторизации выглядит так
5E1A5560B34F7908A5887075B80BAD7979F58D29C49DCF330277278BE67CBE9A